# Django + mongoengine, connect to mongo when used as auxiliary database

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm trying to connect to mongodb using mongoengine.

Mysql is my default database, and I have 'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth' in my installed apps.  I removed the 'AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'' due to errors about not having a default connection.

I use mongo with celery so I don't think there's a problem with the setup.  This is how I am attempting to connect - the code is in views.py

```
from mongoengine import connect

my_connect = connect('my_db', alias='mongo')
test = test(name='a_name', desc='a desc')
test.save(using='mongo')
my_connect.connection.disconnect()
```

Comment: What errors do you get? And do you need the `disconnect()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have finally managed to sort this out:

```
#settings.py
from mongoengine import register_connection
register_connection(alias='default',name='db_name')

#models.py
from mongoengine import Document, StringField (etc)

class my_col(Document):
    field_a = StringField() 

#in your app
from mongoengine import connect
my_con = connect('db_name', alias='default')
item = my_col(field_a='something')
item.save()
my_con.disconnect()
```

Comment: Works w/o `my_con.disconnect()` on Django==1.8.4 & mongoengine==0.10.0